# Let $x=\{a,b\}$ be a set. Then, $x\in\{a,b\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $x=\{a,b\}$ be a set. Then, $x\in\{a,b\}$?

I think: Yes. So, why?

Comment: No set is a member of itself.

Comment: @AdamHughes Because Russel paradox?

Comment: What Russel paradox has an interest here ?

Comment: @Surb Let $x=${$y$} and $y=${$x$}. Then, we can have $x\in y\in x\in y\in x\in y\in$...

Comment: @Surb Actually, we cannot have. Yet, Assume that we have this. So, if $x=${$y$} and $y=${$x$} then, how it is equal to $x\in y\in x\in y\in x\in y\in$... ?

Answer (score 2):

$\{a,b\}$ is a subset of $\{a,b\}$, but it's not an element of $\{a,b\}$. So you have that $x\subset \{a,b\}$, but $x\notin\{a,b\}$. Notice that if $$A=\{a,b;\{a,b\}\},$$
and if you set $x=\{a,b\}$, then, in these conditions, you have that $x\in A$ and $x\subset A$.

Answer (score 2):

No! Actually it is not! The elements of $x=\{a,b\}$ are exactly $a$ and $b$ and therefore you could perfectly say $a \in x$ or $b\in x$. However $x=\{a,b\} \notin \{a,b\}$ A different thing would be if you had

$y=\{\{a,b\},\{a\}\}$. Now the elements of this set are $\{a,b\}$ and $\{a\}$ and in this case you could say $x=\{a,b\}\in y$